# Точка в конце фразы, если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит многоточие

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, цитата

Он подчеркнул: «Наш студент должен стать... Для него важно понять на практике, как устроен аппарат управления, как он функционирует, как работают средства массовой информации…».
Он сказал: «Мы озабочены тремя ключевыми моментами: это подготовленные педагоги, учебные программы и пособия и обеспечение равного доступа ко всем модулям в рамках предметной области…».
Нужны ли точки в конце этих предложений? Многоточия в КОНЦЕ цитат означают незаконченную мысль.
Объяснений очень много, но всё равно не понятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точки не нужны. Грамота.ру пишет следующее.

> В конце фразы после закрывающих цитату кавычек:
>
> ...
>
> в) не ставят никаких знаков, если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит
>   многоточие, вопросительный или восклицательный знак, а заключенная в
>   кавычки цитата является самостоятельным предложением (таковы, как
>   правило, все цитаты после двоеточия, отделяющего их от предшествующих
>   им слов цитирующего):
>
> *Глава заканчивается словами: «Прощай, философия, прощай, молодость,
>   прощай, Германия!»*

Я считаю, что здесь всё понятно.

Answer (score 3):

Точка  после многоточия и закрывающих цитату кавычек **не ставится,** если цитата оформлена по образцу прямой речи, но **точка ставится,** если она оформлена как придаточное предложение (косвенная речь):

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=165#pp165

2. Если цитата, заканчивающаяся многоточием, не является самостоятельным предложением, то после нее ставится точка:
   **М. В. Ломоносов писал, что «красота, великолепие, сила и богатство российского языка явствует довольно из книг, в прошлые века писанных…».**

Если же цитата, заканчивающаяся многоточием, является самостоятельным предложением, то после кавычек точка не ставится (как при прямой речи): **В. Г. Белинский писал: «В “Онегине” все части органически сочленены…»**

Comment: Поправка: обсуждается точка не в конце цитаты, а в конце всей фразы, содержащей цитату.

Comment: Ну и я о том же.  Только цитата может быть оформлена двумя способами: как прямая речь без точки в конце и как косвенная речь с точкой в конце. Именно это обычно вызывает трудность и непонимание.  Это чисто ЗРИТЕЛЬНОЕ ВОСПРИЯТИЕ: многоточие, кавычки, а точка то ставится, то не ставится.

Comment: А у Вас в ответе "точка в конце **цитаты**". Это описка?

Comment: Наверное, неточность. Просто у Розенталя есть выражение "если цитата является самостоятельным предложением...".

Comment: *М. В. Ломоносов писал, что «красота, великолепие, сила и богатство российского языка явствует довольно из книг, в прошлые века писанных…»* Про всем уважении к Розенталю, зачем здесь вообще многоточие? Что оно дает читателю? При таком цитировании обязательно показывать, что предложение приведено не целиком?

Comment: Если предложение не закончено, то надо ставить многоточие. Это и есть информация для читателя.

Comment: У меня дословное выражение является несогласованным определением.